# O que há de errado neste código em delphi?

Tags: delphi, quickreport

No onCreate do mainform, tenho o seguinte código:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 QuickRep1.Prepare;
 QuickRep1.Printer.Load('arquivo.qrp');
 QuickRep1.ExportToFilter(TQRAsciiExportFilter.Create('teste.txt'));
 QuickRep1.Free;
end;
```

Ele deve abrir um arquivo QRP e salvar como TXT. Ele até cria o teste.txt, mas o arquivo está em branco, com 0kb. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Para ter certeza eu precisaria baixar o componente, mas tenho uma duvida. O arquivo 'arquivo.qrp' está junto com o executável da aplicação ? Tenta especificar o caminho dele. Ex: 'c:/arquivo.qrp'.

Comment: Sim, está junto. Quando eu dou um QuickRep1.Printer.Preview; o arquivo é exibido, sinal de que ele está sendo carregado corretamente

Comment: Pode me dizer qual a versão do QuickReport está utilizando ?

Comment: é a versão 5.02

Comment: Não consegui montar o código como o seu exemplo. Na parte do `QuickRep1.Printer.Load('arquivo.qrp');` tiver que trocar por `QuickRep1.QRPrinter.Load('arquivo.qrp');` Alem disso, consegue disponibilizar um arquivo de extenção .qrp para testes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

Crie 2 novas variáveis (na uses interface declare: `QRPrntr`):

```
  vFilterLibrary : TQRExportFilterLibraryEntry;
  vExportFilter  : TQRExportFilter;
```

Depois do Prepare:

```
  vFilterLibrary := QRExportFilterLibrary.GetFilterByExtension('txt');
  vExportFilter  := vFilterLibrary.ExportFilterClass.Create(vNomeAnexo);
  QuickRep1.ExportToFilter(vExportFilter);
```

O que estamos fazendo é localizar o `Filter` pela extensão, depois pedimos para ele criar o arquivo (forma correta).

Nota: Para este procedimento funcionar, o formulário report que será exportado deve possuir um `Filter` que exporte com a extensão txt!

Comment: Compilou, mas na execução deu o seguinte erro: `raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0050CBD8 in Module 'Project1.exe'. 'Read of address 000000004'`. Na seguinte linha:  `vExportFilter  := vFilterLibrary.ExportFilterClass.Create('teste.txt');`

Comment: Uma violação nesta linha só pode ocorrer se não existir no formulário um filter para a extensão mencionada!

Comment: Eu testei aqui, coloquei todos os filters do qreport no form, tentei com outro formato, mas ainda dá violação :(